# Log Detail Report - DB Error when viewing an update to a contact

Tags: database, reports, logs, logging

Developer question. Civi 5.71.1 on Drupal 10 with a separate db for CiviCRM logs.

#### Symptom

I'm getting many "DB Error: no such field" errors when viewing "update" changes in the Log Detail Report, linked from either the Log Summary Report or the contact's Change Log.

[image]

#### Investigation

When I trigger the error, the Civi error log shows a SQL error (see below). It seems the [`getDiffs()` function in ReportDetail.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/37a153b3f571a7e330572e168e4da610f614f41e/CRM/Logging/ReportDetail.php#L151) is passing in the wrong table parameter to `diffsInTable()` on line 151 as `log_civicrm_saved_search` which feeds into the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement. That table param should probably be `log_civicrm_contact` (or one of the custom field value tables) since we're looking at an update to an Individual's record.

#### Possibly Related

I've only noticed these errors after I toggled the Civicrm Detailed Logging from ON to OFF (to do some data imports) and then ON again. I've also got the Civicrm detail log tables in a separate database on the same mysql server. Not sure if those are contributing factors.

#### What I've tried

From the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/troubleshooting/) I've tried:

- clearing the Civi cache via the web UI and via `/civicrm/clearcache`.
- Directory cleanup (&directoryCleanup=3)
- Trigger rebuild (&triggerRebuild=1)

Could the civi db be out of sync somehow with the civicrm log db?

Appreciate any ideas!

#### Civi Error Log

Here are relevant snippets from the Civi error log:

```
        4 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php"
          "line" => 966
          "function" => "raiseError"
          "class" => "DB_common"
          "object" => DB_mysqli {#1713}
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => array:5 [
            0 => -19
            1 => null
            2 => null
            3 => """
              \n
              SELECT DISTINCT lt.id FROM `mydb_civicrm_log`.`log_civicrm_saved_search` lt\n
              \n
              WHERE lt.log_conn_id = '6606f5949e9f1r9nW'\n
                  \n
                      AND lt.log_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2024-03-29 12:08:39', INTERVAL 10 SECOND) AND DATE_ADD('2024-03-29 12:08:39', INTERVAL 10 SECOND)\n
                    \n
                  AND contact_id = 431 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_id' in 'where clause']
              """
            4 => "1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_id' in 'where clause'"
          ]
        ]
        5 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php"
          "line" => 413
          "function" => "mysqliRaiseError"
          "class" => "DB_mysqli"
          "object" => DB_mysqli {#1713}
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => []
        ]
        6 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php"
          "line" => 1241
          "function" => "simpleQuery"
          "class" => "DB_mysqli"
          "object" => DB_mysqli {#1713}
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => array:1 [
            0 => """
              \n
              SELECT DISTINCT lt.id FROM `mydb_civicrm_log`.`log_civicrm_saved_search` lt\n
              \n
              WHERE lt.log_conn_id = '6606f5949e9f1r9nW'\n
                  \n
                      AND lt.log_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2024-03-29 12:08:39', INTERVAL 10 SECOND) AND DATE_ADD('2024-03-29 12:08:39', INTERVAL 10 SECOND)\n
                    \n
                  AND contact_id = 431
              """
          ]
        ]
```

```
        11 => array:6 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Logging/Differ.php"
          "line" => 142
          "function" => "executeQuery"
          "class" => "CRM_Core_DAO"
          "type" => "::"
          "args" => array:2 [
            0 => """
              \n
              SELECT DISTINCT lt.id FROM `mydb_civicrm_log`.`log_civicrm_saved_search` lt\n
              \n
              WHERE lt.log_conn_id = %1\n
                  \n
                      AND lt.log_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(%2, INTERVAL 10 SECOND) AND DATE_ADD(%2, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)\n
                    \n
                  AND contact_id = %3
              """
            1 => array:3 [
              1 => array:2 [
                0 => "6606f5949e9f1r9nW"
                1 => "String"
              ]
              3 => array:2 [
                0 => 431
                1 => "Integer"
              ]
              2 => array:2 [
                0 => "2024-03-29 12:08:39"
                1 => "String"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
        12 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Logging/ReportDetail.php"
          "line" => 164
          "function" => "diffsInTable"
          "class" => "CRM_Logging_Differ"
          "object" => CRM_Logging_Differ {#3358
            -db: "mydb_civicrm_log"
            -log_conn_id: "6606f5949e9f1r9nW"
            -log_date: "2024-03-29 12:08:39"
            -interval: "10 SECOND"
          }
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => array:2 [
            0 => "civicrm_saved_search"
            1 => 431
          ]
        ]
        13 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Logging/ReportDetail.php"
          "line" => 151
          "function" => "diffsInTable"
          "class" => "CRM_Logging_ReportDetail"
          "object" => CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingDetail {#3122
            +_attributes: array:5 [
              "action" => "/civicrm/report/instance/106"
              "method" => "post"
              "name" => "LoggingDetail"
              "id" => "LoggingDetail"
              "class" => "CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingDetail crm-report-form"
            ]
--- snip ---
            #tables: array:78 [
              0 => "civicrm_contact"
              1 => "civicrm_saved_search"
              2 => "civicrm_batch"
              3 => "civicrm_mailing_abtest"
--- snip ---
            ]
            #interval: "10 SECOND"
            #dblimit: 50
            #dboffset: 0
            #altered_name: "name 1"
            #altered_by: "name 2"
            #altered_by_id: 123
            #layout: null
            #detail: "logging/contact/detail"
            #summary: "logging/contact/summary"
            #differ: CRM_Logging_Differ {#3358}
            #diffs: []
          }
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => array:1 [
            0 => "civicrm_saved_search"
          ]
        ]
        14 => array:7 [
          "file" => "/home/mywebsite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Logging/ReportDetail.php"
          "line" => 136
          "function" => "getDiffs"
          "class" => "CRM_Logging_ReportDetail"
          "object" => CRM_Report_Form_Contact_LoggingDetail {#3122}
          "type" => "->"
          "args" => []
        ]
```